# How to remove matching words from array?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays..

Eg:

```
A = [ "uparea" , "selection"]

B = ["upareasetting"]
```

I want to print

```
"upareaselectionsetting"
```

Need to remove `"uparea"` in b ???

Comment: Do you '*Need to remove "uparea" in b*' or do you need to remove all elements of A from all elements of B? It's a vague example given the title.

Comment: Need to compare a and b and then remove matching words

Answer (score 0):

First loop through each item in `A` to check whether the current word exist in `B`. If exist then remove that from `B`. Finally concatenate and join both array's to get the expected output.

Try the following with `forEach()`, `concat()` and `join()`:

```js
let A = [ "uparea" , "selection"]
let B = ["upareasetting"];
A.forEach(function(i){
  if(B[0].indexOf(i) > -1)
    B = B[0].replace(i, '');
});
let res = A.concat(B).join('');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const A = ["uparea", "selection"],
  B = ["upareasetting"];

console.log(
  A.join("") +
  B.map(
    item => item.replace(/uparea/, "")
  ).join("")
);

// upareaselectionsetting
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, hope it helps.

```
function removeMatchingWords(a, b) {
    result_string = "";
    for (let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        result_string += a[i];
        for (let j=0; j<b.length; j++) {
            if (b[j].includes(a[i])) {
                b[j] = b[j].replace(a[i], "");
            }
        }
    }
    for (let k=0; k<b.length; k++) {
        result_string += b[k];
    }
    return result_string;
};
```